# "Right" Way to Perform Admin Tasks?

Tags: php, magento, admin, magento-1.5

I'm trying to put together an admin module that can perform some custom sorting tasks and I've run into a question I can't seem to find an answer to.  Basically, I added a section to the Admin config with a few buttons that scan recent orders and set some custom values on the order items that I can use later.  To do this, I added a button to the *system.xml* that redirects to a controller.  The controller performs the necessary task (or instantiates a model to do so) and then needs to redirect back to the admin page it came from.  This is the part that has me confused.  I can't seem to figure out the best way to pass the current URL from the admin section through to the controller so the controller knows where to redirect back to.  Sure, I could hard code it, but I'd really rather not.  Furthermore, is this even the right way to do it?  If there's no layout for the controller and it's only purpose is to do stuff on button click, is there a better way to go about it?

Assuming this is the correct way to go about this, here are some chunks from my files for reference.

### system.xml

Here's the section of *system.xml* that declares the button.  Note that I'm using a custom frontend_model class because it was the only way I could get this to work (is there a better way?)

```
<fields>
    <calcmargin translate="label">
        <label>Calculate Margins</label>
        <comment>
            <![CDATA[Calculates the order margins]]>
        </comment>
        <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
        <frontend_model>sorting/source_buttons_calcmargin</frontend_model>
        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </calcmargin>
</fields>
```

### config.xml

In config.xml, I declare my admin router (among other things)

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <sorting>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>VPS_Sorting</module>
                <frontName>sorting</frontName>
            </args>
        </sorting>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

### Button Source

Here's the _*getElementHtml* function from my source button class

```
public function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    //save the current URL in the sorting/data singleton for future use
    Mage::getSingleton('sorting/data')->setSortingReturnUrl(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());

    $this->setElement($element);

    $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
    ->setType('button')
    ->setClass('scalable')
    ->setLabel($this->buttonLabel)
    ->setOnClick("setLocation('$this->buttonUrl')")
    ->toHtml();

    return $html;
}
```

**NOTE:** *$this->buttonUrl* is set earlier using `$this->getUrl('sorting/index/calcmargin')`

In this case, I have a model called *Data.php* that I instantiate using *getSingleton* and set the return URL.

### IndexController

```
public function calcmarginAction()
{
    $orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

    foreach($orderCollection as $order)
    {
        //Do Stuff
        //...
    }

    echo "DONE...now return to " . Mage::getSingleton('sorting/data')->getSortingReturnUrl();
    //outputs: 'DONE...now return to '...so clearly the value wasn't saved
}
```

Unfortunately, when it gets over to the controller, that value is no longer there.  So I guess I don't really understand how singletons work and how long they stick around...

I also tried saving the value in the *core/session* singleton, but that didn't work either.

So, if you're still with me, any thoughts on what I should do?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried saving it to adminhtml/session singleton?

Comment: I hadn't...just did, and it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've worked out a singleton is only valid for the page request, to persist longer than that and you need sessions. However there is a simpler way with controllers, put this in place of your echo;

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

As an aside I wouldn't think the config section would be ideal for a button that performs an action. Perhaps the *System > Tools* menu instead...

Comment: Thanks!  That worked perfectly.  I'll look at relocating the action to the Tools menu, but for now, it's good where it is :)  One additional question...how can I add a success message to the message block after I return back from the controller?

Comment: Figured out the message question.  `Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess("Success!!")`.  Also, it's important to note that an admin controller needs to extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` for everything to work correctly...that one got me...

Comment: Regarding messages the controller also has a `_getSession()` shortcut which retrieves the adminhtml singleton for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an actual redirect, as in a HTTP redirect? Or you are doing a forward to a different controller?

If you are doing an actual redirect that's hideous. Don't do it. Stop. Redesign entirely.

You should create an action helper which contains your calc margin code.

To answer your other question, if there is no layout or view script for the Controller (due to the nature of what the controller does), then it shouldn't be called by the user. It would most likely be something like a cron job where layouts are disabled.

The better way to do what you want would be to use Action Helpers. Controllers are mapped from individual requests, so, one route (or many routes) would map to a single controller. However, if some code is used by lots of controllers, then it should be an action helper.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not sure I fully understand though.  Simply put, what I want is a button in the system config section that runs the calc margin code.  The only way I knew to do that was have the button redirect to a controller and then redirect back.  If that's not right, then please provide an example of what you mean.

Comment: @Laykes, it's quite common to POST to one controller which then redirects to another URL. That way the user doesn't get warning messages from their browser about resubmitting forms when they use a back button.

Comment: @clockworkgeek - Yes I do that also. Under Zend Framework you have the helper flashMessenger for that exact purpose. But, that current situation that he just highlighted I don'tt think covers one of those scenarios.